# IIS Server connection in Jdeveloper BPEL?

Tags: connection, jdeveloper, bpel

So I am writing a webservice in BPEL, but coming up with a few obstacles due to not being very familiar with Jdeveloper. Basic questions first. How can I create a new application server connection to an IIS Server? I currently have a data centric webservice deployed to an IIS server in C# that I need to connect to through my BPEL model. So basically an external webservice connection is required. Any help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import the WSDL of your C# service into JDeveloper and define a partnerlink for that. Then you can call the service using the BPEL invoke activity.

Comment: Thank you. I was getting thrown by Jdeveloepr asking if it should autogenerate a wsdl for that partnerlink as no partnerlinks were defined in the C# wsdl file. Did not realise that the new WSDL was actually a ref to the actual wsdl.

Comment: Yes, partner link types (basically one end of a partner link) are defined using a WSDL extension. So to add them to a defined WSDL, they are either put into the WSDL it self, or a new WSDL file is created, which just contains the partner link types and imports the original WSDL.